# Symfony execute Action and stay on page

Tags: php, symfony1

I want to execute a Action and stay on the same page.

I created the link to eh action like this:

```
<?php  echo(link_to('Add to Watchlist', 'housing/addToWatchlist')) ?>
```

which executes this action with a redirect

```
echo('ADDING TO THA WATCHLIST');
$referrer = $request->getReferer();
return $this->redirect($referrer);
```

as suggested here: [symfony link to change language and stay on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343217/symfony-link-to-change-language-and-stay-on-the-page)

This solution works but unnecessary reloads the page, which may be necessary to change the language but not to add an item to a Watchlist.

Answer (score 1):

Without reloading the page you need to use Javascript and an Ajax approach. 
http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Propel/en/18

Also check out `link_to_remote`.